# pthread_atfork fails to compile when declaring -nostartfiles

Tags: c, pthreads, shared-libraries, fork, glibc

I have an old application that uses the pthread_atfork function from the pthread library to register a child hook.  I'm in the process of moving the application to a newer build environment which uses glibc 2.14.90. pthread_atfork appears to have been essentially removed from the pthread library back in 2002, and one of the shared libraries we create will no longer compile.

Here is the code in question:

```
void
_init(void)
{
    static int first = 1;
    if ( first ) {
        pthread_atfork(NULL,NULL,_init);
        first = 0;
    }
    {
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid,0,startUp,0);
    }
    return;
}
```

The pthread_atfork call registers _init as a child hook, to be run in the child process every time there's a fork.  Init just creates a new thread to execute startUp which is an initialization function that sets up stuff like files, mutexes, reads in initialization parameters, etc...

Since pthread_atfork is hidden in glibc 2.14, is there a another way to register the same kind of hook so that init gets run at fork?  I would prefer to use the standard lib without any modification, to preserve portability of the build environment.

glibc 2.14 source code is here, for those interested (pthread_atfork files are under the nptl directory):

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;h=d1e550124ee36b8b62af8984e4b829622a60f725;hb=356f8bc660a154a07b03da7c536831da5c8f74fe

Compilation error I receive:

gcc -g  -nostartfiles -o mto.so -shared -I mto.c -lnsl -lresolv -lrt -lm -lpthread -ldl

**/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a(pthread_atfork.oS): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object**

*$ gcc -v*

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC)

*$ ldd --version*

ldd (GNU libc) 2.14.90
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libpthread.a|grep -C 1 atfork
00008150 W __pread64
000060b0 T __pthread_atfork
00002ab0 T __pthread_attr_destroy
--
00007ba0 W __recvmsg
         U __register_atfork
00008c10 T __res_state
--
00008150 W pread64
000060b0 T pthread_atfork
00002ab0 T pthread_attr_destroy
```

.

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a

pthread_atfork.oS:
         U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         w __dso_handle
00000000 T __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
00000000 T __pthread_atfork
         U __register_atfork
00000000 T pthread_atfork
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure what makes you think `pthread_atfork` was removed; it was not. If you're experiencing an actual problem, please show the error messages you're getting. Keep in mind that `_init` is a particularly bad name for a function. It's in the reserved namespace and may end up getting treated specially by the linking process.

Comment: Read the Rationale in the POSIX 2008 specification for [`pthread_atfork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_atfork.html) and you will see a lot of past tense: _The `pthread_atfork()` function was intended to provide…The expected usage was…This is good in theory, but in reality not practical…there is no suitable solution for functionality which requires non-atomic operations to be protected through mutexes and locks…the POSIX.1 standard…requires that the child process after `fork()` in a multi-threaded process only calls async-signal-safe interfaces._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's true that it's informally deprecated in POSIX, but it's not removed from glibc, which still attempts to support ancient versions of POSIX, and even current POSIX still provides `pthread_atfork`.

Comment: @ktbiz: That's not the right way to make code that runs automatically when a library is loaded. You should use `__attribute__((__constructor__))`.

Comment: @R.. _init is used in conjunction with -nostartfiles here.  I added the compile time error, gcc -v, and ldd --version to my post.

Comment: @ktbiz: Get rid of `-nostartfiles` and I suspect your problem will go away.

Comment: @R.. That will cause a conflict because _init and _fini are defined.  pthread is explicitly linked so it shouldn't be an issue.

    `multiple definition of _init
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
    multiple definition of _fini
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.6.3/../../../crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @ktbiz: Don't use the name `_init`. Rename your function to something else, or just make it static, and add `__attribute__((__constructor__))` to it. Naming a function `_init` is an invalid and deprecated way to make it run at module load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the outer wrapper function `pthread_atfork` seems to have been moved to `libpthread_nonshared.a` so that it can identify the library calling it, presumably so that the installed handlers can be removed if/when the library is unloaded, and it achieves this by referencing the `__dso_handle` symbol which is defined in the start files, which you are intentionally omitting. **You can't do this.** Omitting start files is only valid for some low-level purposes; it's not compatible with linking any part of the standard library.

Apparently the reason you're using `-nostartfiles` is to be able to write your own `_init` function that will run when the library is loaded, since without `-nostartfiles` it causes a linker error due to a clash with the same-name function in `crti.o`. Unfortunately this is the wrong fix.

Redefining `_init` to run code at library load time is an unsupported hack that was deprecated a long time ago. The correct way to run code at library load time is to apply `__attribute__((__constructor__))` to the function you want to run. Give the function a name that won't clash with anything, or just make it `static` so you don't have to worry about its name clashing.

Comment: Oddly enough, the `__attribute__((__constructor__)) _init(void)` declaration was already in the file, but it was tucked away inside an `#ifdef (linux)` statement up at the top. Why wasn't the function name changed? Perhaps laziness or an attempt to keep this code compatible for very old versions of gcc. This code also has to compile under the sun compiler on solaris, which has its own initialization def `#define _init _localInit` tucked away in an `#ifdef` statement.

I changed the name of the _init function and got rid of -nostartfiles (and _fini).

Thank you for your assistance.